# readAsText on json file return [object]

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

**This is my code**

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 100 * 1024 * 1024, function (filesystem) {
                    fs = filesystem;
                    fs.root.getFile('library.json',{create:true},function(entry) {
                        console.log(entry);
                        entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                            writer.write(new Blob(library));
                            entry.file(function(file) {
                               var fileReader = new FileReader();
                                fileReader.onloadend = function() {
                                    console.log(fileReader.result);
                                }
                                fileReader.readAsText(file); 
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }, null);
```

It's supposed to return something like this:

```
[
    {prop:'2342',prop2:'awqe'},
    {prop:'1231',prop2:'asdasd'}
]
```

But right now it returns this: `[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object`

How do  i change this behavious?

> I'm working with chrome packaged app

Comment: What's `library` in `new Blob(library)`?

Comment: is the thing that is supposed to be returned. It's an array with objects inside

Comment: But `readAsText` returns a string, presumably that `Blob` should contain `plain/text`, no? Sounds like you're not serializing those objects to text.

Comment: shouldnt `Blob` return full content of the array as plain text though?

Comment: No, it only contains a byte representation of the data. You'd need to construct it like: `new Blob([JSON.stringify(library)], {type : 'text/plain'});` on on the inverse, parse it like `JSON.parse(fileReader.result)`